# Laravel & Php 7.1 parse or syntax error with ::class keyword

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

As the title says, in Laravel 5.4 & PHP 7.1  classname (ClassName::class) resolution is not working as expected.

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Modules\Location\Models\Location;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model 
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Location::class);
    }
}
```

Yields the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)...`

Is there some extension or something I am missing in my PHP install?

Comment: have you tried using another class ? Or using full FQNS ? Maybe you have a namespace collision somewhere or something like that. I haven't noticed any issue with ::class in php 7.1

Comment: I suggest you double-check that you are indeed running PHP/7. You may not be the first one who has two side-by-side PHP installations.

Comment: try $this->hasMany("App\Model\Location");

Comment: @Sohel0415  That is what I am using currently.  Actually `$this->hasMany('App\Modules\Location\Models\Location', 'account_id');` Works perfectly

Comment: Can a missing or unrecognised class actually trigger a parse error?

Comment: try composer update and composer dump-autoload, sometimes a missing file can cause problems

Comment: can you add your controller code where this is causing problems??

Comment: @Sohel0415 This did it!   Actually it seems that composer dump-autoload or php artisan module:optimize which I also ran  did the trick.  I don't know if you want to add it as an answer or not, but if you do I will accept it.  (the artisan command is from caffinated modules)

Comment: ha ha, sometimes problems are not really a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from comment :) -

```
try composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Running `composer update` is no the best advice if you don't have tests in your app

Comment: I did not use the `update` command just `dump-autoload`.   Also a warning that `composer update` is a bad idea on a production server.

Comment: yeah, i got it, in that case what is your suggestion to update/generate the missing files?

Comment: I also was running the caffinated modules (https://github.com/caffeinated/modules)  which may have contributed to this.   For anyone in the same situation try running `php artisan module:optimize:`

Comment: @Sohel0415  Is your comment above (..what is your suggestion..)  directed to me or Marcin?

Comment: @skribe it was meant for Marcin

Answer (score -1):

Try this once,

```
 return $this->hasMany('model location');
```